# Is it possible to  create a multitype multicolumn index?

Tags: postgresql

If a table have a column A which is geometry type,and column B which is timestamp(1) without time zone type,
Does PostgreSQL allow to  create a multitype multicolumn index on column A and column B ?

```
the index column : (columnA, column B)
```

I want to create a gist index on the part column column A and create a btree index on the part column  columnB;

The folloing is my case,I want to optimize the follwing sql.

```
SELECT id,content,the_geo,lon,lat,skyid,addtime FROM mapfriends.user_map_book 
where          the_geo && mapfriends.ST_BUFFER(mapfriends.geometryfromtext('POINT(100.54687 36.06684)'),0.001)     
order by addtime desc limit 30
```

index of the table

```
db_lbs=> \d mapfriends.user_map_book
                                           Table "mapfriends.user_map_book"
    Column    |              Type              |                               Modifiers                               
--------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                        | not null default nextval('mapfriends.user_map_book_id_seq'::regclass)
 content      | character varying(100)         | 
 lon          | double precision               | 
 lat          | double precision               | 
 skyid        | integer                        | 
 addtime      | timestamp(1) without time zone | default now()
 the_geo      | mapfriends.geometry            | 
 viewcount    | integer                        | default 0
 lastreadtime | timestamp without time zone    | 
 ischeck      | boolean                        | 
Indexes:
    "user_map_book_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_map_book_skyid" btree (skyid, addtime)
    "idx_user_map_book_atime" btree (addtime DESC)
    "user_map_book_idx_gin" gist ((the_geo::box))
```

Comment: As suggested by Frank Heikens, have you tried? Does it work? Also, have you seen [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gist.html) ? It may be your answer. I have the same question with GIN, for a (tsvector , date) index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html):

> Currently, only the B-tree, GiST and GIN index types support
>   multicolumn indexes.

Just give it a try!